# Hot plugging a USB to serial cable to get a login prompt

Tags: usb

Using 2020-12-02-raspios-buster-armhf-lite I have attached a USB
to serial cable and enabled logins with

```
sudo systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
sudo systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0.service
```

This works fine.  I can attach the serial cable to a PC and login.
However if I disconnect the USB cable from the Raspberry Pi then
reconnect it, I can no logger get a login prompt.  Or if I boot the
Pi without the USB cable attached I can't get a login prompt after
plugging it in.  It seems the USB cable has to be attached at boot
time.  Is there anyway to "hot plug" the USB cable and get a login
prompt?

My goal is to have a totally headless Pi (with no networking) where
if I need to login I can attach a USB to serial cable and get a
login prompt.

Comment: If you do not enable them and connect to the serial port and ground do you not end up on the console?  You may need to confirm console using the serial port and nothing else can use it in raspi-config

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of Googling I have come up with the following solution.
Instead of the above, create these 2 files:

/etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-serial-login.rules

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="usb-serial-login.service"
```

/etc/systemd/system/usb-serial-login.service

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl start serial-getty@ttyUSB0
```

This seems to give a login prompt no matter when the USB cable is
attached.